# Undefined Array position when using big callback function

Tags: javascript, undefined, undefined-index

So, our professor asked to make a brute force Traveling Salesman in JavaScript, this is the permutation algorithm i'm using:

```
function heapPermute(A, callback){
  var n = A.length;
  var c = [];
  var i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    c[i] = 0;
  }

  callback(A);

  i = 0;
  while(i < n){
    if(c[i] < i){
      if(i % 2){
        swap(A, c[i], i);
      }else{
        swap(A, 0, i);
      }
      callback(A);
      c[i]++;
      i = 0;
    }else{
      c[i] = 0;
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

And call it like the following:

```
heapPermute(ArrayOfIndex, function(input){
    console.log(input);
});
```

console output with ArrayOfIndex = [1,2,3]

```
Array [ 0, 1, 2 ]
Array [ 1, 0, 2 ]
Array [ 2, 0, 1 ]
Array [ 0, 2, 1 ]
Array [ 1, 2, 0 ]
Array [ 2, 1, 0 ]
```

Thing is, when i use simple callback functions like console.log() the code runs with no problem and console logs all permutations, but if i try to do use the indexes to calculate the best route, i get Undefined when accessing the array positions.

```
bestDistance = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
distMatrix = //Matrix read from .json;
bestRoute = [];

function checkIfBestRoute(route){

  console.log(route);   //this prints an Array with 2 undefined positions


  //distMatrix is global
  var distance = distMatrix[route[route.length - 1]][route[0]];    //Undefined route[0]

  for(var i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++){
    distance += distMatrix[route[i]][route[i + 1]];
  }

  if(distance < bestDistance){
    bestDistance = distance;
    bestRoute = route.splice(0);
  }
}

heapPermute(ArrayOfIndex, checkIfBestRoute);    //Undefined route[0] trace
```

Console output when calling the function like the block above with ArrayOfIndex = [0, 1, 2, 3]

```
Array [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
Array [ undefined, undefined ]
TypeError: route[0] is undefined
```

Comment: `console.log` lies when logging things like arrays. What you see in the console is not a snapshot of the array, it's the "final" state of the array - what is the var `ArrayOf Index` when you call heapPermute?

Comment: Its an array containing all the Index chosen by the user to create a route,

Comment: so, an array of numbers? you got some globals like `bestDistance` and `bestRoute` and `distMatrix` that you haven't shown either, so, bit hard to tell you what you've done wrong

Comment: last Block edited

Comment: To save you a bit of headache, either use breakpoints (or `debugger;` statement) to stop the code at the point you wish to inspect it, or use `console.log(JSON.stringify(...))` to keep `console.log` honest.

Comment: output with JSON.strinfy is the same as stated